# What are the odds for the last hearts card being drawn 37th.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to find the odds for the last hearts card (in a regular deck of 52 cards, 13 are hearts) being drawn 37th.

I understand it means all other 12 hearts card need to be drawn in the first 36 cards, and then the next card to be the last hearts card.

So I tried to solve it like $\Large\frac{\binom{52}{24}*36!*15!}{52!}$ thinking I need to choose 24 other card to be with the 12 hearts in the first 36, assume the next one is the last hearts card, and then multiply by all the order possibilities for the first 36 and last 15 (not including the 37th), divided by all sorts of a deck of cards. Why is my thinking wrong?

I know the answer is $\Large\frac{\binom{36}{12}}{\binom{52}{13}}$, but I can't understand it fully.

Thanks.

Comment: Your ${52 \choose 24}$ should be replaced by ${39 \choose 24} \times {13 \choose 12}$: in the first 36 cards, you have 24 taken from the other three suits and 12 hearts. Next, you can simplify to arrive to the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning works, but you made two mistakes.

Firstly, the 24 other cards need to be non-hearts, so are not chosen from the full deck of 52 cards but from the set of 39 non-hearts cards.

Secondly, you forgot to choose which hearts card is going to be the last one (or equivalently, which 12 hearts cards occur in the first 36 cards of the deck).

Once you fix those two mistakes, you will get the same value as the given answer, though written in a different form.

The given answer is the result of a different method. The card values don't matter, nor do the suits of the non-hearts cards. So you can picture the deck as being made of 13 identical hearts cards, and 39 identical non-hearts cards. Such a deck has $\binom{52}{13}$ possible orderings, all equally probable, determined by which of the 13 locations in the deck contain a hearts card. The arrangements we are interested in all end in a heart followed by 15 non-hearts, with the only variation being in the arrangement of the first 36 cards of which 12 cards are hearts. So there are $\binom{36}{12}$ of these arrangements, leading to the given answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got to the correct answer by my method and also understood the reasoning behind the second one!